# Meta viewport tag and css media queries

Tags: html, css, ipad, safari, viewport

I have a problem with CSS media queries using together with meta viewport tag.
I am making iPad webapp that will work inside standalone view on home screen.

This is the CSS:

```
.header_portrait {

    position: relative;
    top: 0px;
    left: 0px;
    background: #ccc;
    width: 1536px;
    height: 219px;

}

.header_landscape {

    position: relative;
    top: 0px;
    left: 0px;
    background: #fff;
    width: 1536px;
    height: 219px;

}

@media only screen and (max-device-width: 1024px) and (orientation:portrait) { 
    .header_landscape { display: none; }
}
@media only screen and (max-device-width: 1024px) and (orientation:landscape) { 
    .header_portrait { display: none; }
}
```

This is part of HTML `<head>`:

```
<meta id="viewport" name="viewport" content="user-scalable=0, width=device-width, height=device-height, initial-scale=0.5, maximum-scale=0.5" />
<meta name="apple-mobile-web-app-capable" content="yes">
```

This is part of HTML `<body>`:

```
<div class="header_portrait" ontouchmove="togle_touch('disable');">

</div>
<div class="header_landscape" ontouchmove="togle_touch('disable');">

</div>
```

If I remove meta viewport tag from head orientation detection works fine. 
It seems that viewport mess up max-device-width so that CSS media query doesn't detect it as it should.

Any help is greatly appreciated :)

Comment: As an aside should "user-scalable=0" not be "user-scalable=no"? Maybe both work but I've always used "user-scalable=no".

Comment: It doesn't help, also you can use both 0 or no for user-scalable

Answer (score 0):

(Answered in comments or edits. See [Question with no answers, but issue solved in the comments (or extended in chat)](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/251597/question-with-no-answers-but-issue-solved-in-the-comments) )

The OP wrote:

> I have solved this!
>
> Just replace:

```
<meta id="viewport" name="viewport" content="user-scalable=0, width=device-width, height=device-height, initial-scale=0.5, maximum-scale=0.5" />
```

> With:

```
<meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, maximum-scale=0.5" />
```

> It works well for now and in iPad 3 I must test it in iPad 1 and 2...